# XSLT for each loop on simple XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML like this

```
      <filters extra="filters">
<ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="Sort" UNITCODE=""/>
<ISP_WebItem FILTER="Længde" FILTERNAME="51" UNITCODE="cm"/>
<ISP_WebItem FILTER="Højde" FILTERNAME="3.2" UNITCODE="cm"/>
<ISP_WebItem FILTER="Dybde" FILTERNAME="9" UNITCODE="cm"/>
<ISP_WebItem FILTER="Stavlængde" FILTERNAME="11" UNITCODE="cm"/>
      </filters>
```

I want to loop through each ISP_WebItem and display  FILTER,FILTERNAME and UNITCODE.
i have tried some thing like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="filters/ISP_WebItem ">              
          <xsl:value-of  select="FILTER" />
          <xsl:value-of  select="FILTERNAME" />
          <xsl:value-of  select="UNITCODE" />
 </xsl:for-each>
```

but of no use.
and when i put a break point and checked ,I found that code execution does not happen inside for each loop( break point inside for each loop never hits).

I have limited knowledge on XSLT and i know this may be a simple question .but i really need to overcome this.can any one guide me on this.

note: as some people requested for complete XSLT and XML i am publishing it here

Complete XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/">      
<xsl:variable name="p">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="library:Request('pid') != ''">
      <xsl:copy-of select="shop:GetProductFromId(library:Request('pid'))" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of  select="shop:GetProductFromId(shop:UrlInformation()//productid)" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($p)/product/filters"/>
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($p)/product/filters/ISP_WebItem">
    <xsl:value-of  select="@FILTER" />
    <xsl:value-of  select="@FILTERNAME" />
    <xsl:value-of  select="@UNITCODE" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Complete XML

```
    <product>
  <estocklevel>0</estocklevel>
  <url>/product/relief-smal-brevordner-bordeaux-2</url>
  <texts>
    <text language="standard">
      <name>Relief Smal Brevordner, Bordeaux (2)</name>
      <longdescription></longdescription>
      <shortdescription>(10)</shortdescription>
      <htmltitle></htmltitle>
      <metadescription></metadescription>
      <metakeywords></metakeywords>
    </text>
  </texts>
  <name>Relief Smal Brevordner, Bordeaux (2)</name>
  <longdescription></longdescription>
  <shortdescription>(10)</shortdescription>
  <htmltitle></htmltitle>
  <metadescription></metadescription>
  <metakeywords></metakeywords>
  <alternativeitemid></alternativeitemid>
  <alternativeitemrule>0</alternativeitemrule>
  <duties />
  <oncampaign extra="oncampaign">0</oncampaign>
  <minweb extra="minweb">0.000000000000</minweb>
  <stockitem extra="stockitem">0.000000000000</stockitem>
  <isp_model extra="isp_model">Smal</isp_model>
  <produkttype extra="produkttype"></produkttype>
  <filters extra="filters">
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="Bordeaux" UNITCODE=""/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Rygbredde" FILTERNAME="5" UNITCODE="cm"/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Papirstørrelse" FILTERNAME="A4" UNITCODE=""/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Max indhold" FILTERNAME="350 A4 ark" UNITCODE=""/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Rygetiket" FILTERNAME="Med udskiftelig rygetiket" UNITCODE=""/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Materiale 1" FILTERNAME="PP" UNITCODE=""/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Materiale" FILTERNAME="Pap" UNITCODE=""/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Ringtype" FILTERNAME="D" UNITCODE=""/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Antal ringe" FILTERNAME="2" UNITCODE=""/>
  </filters>
</product>
```

Comment: try <xsl:value-of  select="./@FILTER" />

Comment: @vels4j:my answer is incorrect from the for each loop itself so please guide me from there onwards

Comment: Can you show the full XSLT you are using, because the problem may lie elsewhere, outside of the xsl:for-each? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC: I have updated my question with full XSLT.please take a look.

Comment: Thanks! However, your expanded XSLT makes reference to an **product** element in the xsl:for-each, but there are no such product elements in your XML sample. Is your XML sample correct? Perhaps you need to expand that too? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC : I have added complete XML.
But for your notice when i uses this '<xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($p)/product/filters"/>'

I get the first XML i have added in my question(filters).
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

select the attributes by using the @ to distinghish attributes from elements.
Tested on [xslfiddle.net](http://www.xslfiddle.net/)

**xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="filters/ISP_WebItem">
      <xsl:value-of  select="@FILTER" />
      <xsl:value-of  select="@FILTERNAME" />
      <xsl:value-of  select="@UNITCODE" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**xml**

```
<filters extra="filters">
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="Sort" UNITCODE=""/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Længde" FILTERNAME="51" UNITCODE="cm"/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Højde" FILTERNAME="3.2" UNITCODE="cm"/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Dybde" FILTERNAME="9" UNITCODE="cm"/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Stavlængde" FILTERNAME="11" UNITCODE="cm"/>
</filters>
```

**result**

```
<html><head></head><body>FarveSortLængde51cmHøjde3.2cmDybde9cmStavlængde11cm</body></html>
```

Comment: :as far as i had understood code execution does not happen inside this for each loop

Comment: i mean select="filters/ISP_WebItem " condition never satisfies in my code.  i have modified my question with the details.if you still dont understand please tell me

Comment: Is filters the root element? I added a / in my answer

Comment: this one also is not working.
 <xsl:copy-of select="filters"/> is correctly giving me the XML i wrote in the question

Comment: with your xml and mine xslt I have output, so it must be an environment issue. Notice i removed the extra space at the end of the select.

Comment: rene : I am using xml version="1.0" .that is the only thing i can tell you.